# Selecting variable from datalayer in google tag manager

Tags: google-datalayer

My datalayer looks this and i need to pull the email field when the trigger is fired

```
  event-data: {
    type: "hsFormCallback",
    eventName: "onFormSubmit",
    id: "d6c89c91-79aa-4449-bfb9-c5e75ac8e007",
    data: [
      {name: "firstname", value: "xxx"},
      {name: "lastname", value: "xxx"},
      {name: "email", value: "xxx"},
      {name: "weight", value: "x"},
      {name: "height", value: "x"}
    ]
  }
```

Trigger fires correctly and i've tried setting up datalayer variables but they are always undefined

```
event-data.0.data.email 
event-data.data.email 
event-data.data[0].email
```

Anyobe who can help? guess it should be rather simple.